# How to make an Image to show only black text

Tags: php, image-processing

I am trying to do the following:
 I Have a picture I want to make that only text which is written in black remains visible and rest of every colour gets transparent.

I tried to do this using PHP imagecolortransparent function but I am not able to figure out how to make it work.
Any help will be great.
Thanks In advance

Comment: So you want an entirely transparent canvas with just some black text on it and nothing else?

Comment: Yes  i want to do that with an existing image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

There must be an easier way, but until I think of it, this should work:

```
// Read original image
$start = imagecreatefrompng("input.png");

// Make true colour image same size
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($start),imagesy($start));
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 0, 0, 0, 127);
$red=imagecolorallocate($im,255,0,0);
imagesavealpha($im, TRUE);

// Fill the new image with transparency
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $transparent);

// Copy only black pixels across from original to new
for($x=0;$x<imagesx($im);$x++){
   for($y=0;$y<imagesy($im);$y++){
      $rgb = imagecolorat($start,$x,$y);
      if($rgb==0){
         imagesetpixel($im,$x,$y,$black);
      }
   }
}
imagepng($im,"result.png");
```

**Original Answer**

I would do this:

```
// Read original image
$start   = imagecreatefrompng("input.png");

// Create a proper truecolour image the same size that can support transparency
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($start),imagesy($start));
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $transparent);
imagesavealpha($im, TRUE);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$text="This is some quite black text";
imagestring($im,5,0,75,$text,$black);
imagepng($im,"result.png");
```

**input.png**

[image]

**result.png**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply and my apologies for not being clear. I have an input Image that already contains Text written in black.

Comment: Please have another look - I have changed the answer.

Comment: Great Thanks  Mark it looks like it can solve my perpous still if i require any help i will reach out to you..  Sorry I don't have enough reps to upvote your answer.